# Capturing regex group with optional suffix

Tags: regex

I have a strings:

```
ssh://qqq.www.com:9999/project1/repo1.git
ssh://qqq.www.com:9999/project2/repo2
```

My goal is to capture "project1/repo1" and "project2/repo2".

So far I came up with:

```
(?:ssh://qqq\.www\.com:9999/)(.+)(\.git)?
```

But unfortunately the capture group for the first is "project1/repo1.git" instead of "project1/repo1".

How I can modify my regex?

Comment: Like this: `^(?:ssh://qqq\.www\.com:9999/)(.+?)(\.git)?$`, [demo](https://regex101.com/r/BDbpOY/1)

Comment: if what you want to capture can't contain `.`, use a negated character class that won't match the `.` of `.git` : `(?:ssh://qqq\.www\.com:9999/)([^.]+)(\.git)?`. Otherwise use a lazy quantifier : `(?:ssh://qqq\.www\.com:9999/)(.+?)(\.git)?`